# Exclude mentions and retweet twitter api js

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

i am using twitter api to stream the latest @elonmusk's tweet. The problem is that when i do that i also get people retweeting elon musk or mentionning him.

How can i exclude the mentions and retweets.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the tweets by author using the `from:` operator, as shown in the [Twitter API documentation for Stream Premium Operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/premium-operators).

> Note that this is a Premium operator, and can only be used with an Enterprise account.

If you don't have an Enterprise account, you can still use the operator, but not using a stream. Using the [Standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets):

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from:elonmusk
```